# Configure multiple passwords for Redis

Tags: redis

I've set up a redis instance with a password from within the redis.conf file using the

```
# requirepass foobared
```

directive.

I'd like to set up multiple passwords for the Redis instance, so that I can have an application specific password and a different password for each developer accessing the Redis instance (this is for a staging environment), so that I can control access to the instance with some granularity.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
See http://redis.io/topics/security for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From version 6 it's now possible with implementation of ACL, see:
https://redis.io/topics/acl